# How can I alter a sequence in dynamic SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a script to migrate data from one DB to another. One thing I'm not currently able to do is set the nextval of a sequence to the nextval of a sequence in another DB.

I got the difference in values from user_sequences and generated the following dynamic SQL statements:

```
execute immediate 'alter sequence myseq increment by 100';
execute immediate 'select myseq.nextval from dual';
execute immediate 'alter sequence myseq increment by 1';

commit;
```

But nothing happens. What am I missing? If I run the same statements outside the procedure, they work fine:

```
alter sequence myseq increment by 100;
select myseq.nextval from dual;
alter sequence myseq increment by 1;

commit;
```

**EDIT**: Apologies to all for not being clear. I'm actually altering the sequence in the same DB. I'm only getting the value to be set from a remote DB. Perhaps it was unnecessary to mention the remote DB as it doesn't affect things. I only mentioned it to explain what my goals were.

Step 1. I get the nextval of the sequence from a remote DB.

```
select (select last_number
        from dba_sequences@remoteDB
        where upper(sequence_name) = upper(v_sequence_name)) - (select last_number
                                                                from user_sequences
                                                                where upper(sequence_name) = upper(v_sequence_name)) increment_by
from dual;
```

Step 2. I generate dynamic SQL statements with this value:

```
execute immediate 'alter sequence myseq increment by 100';
execute immediate 'select myseq.nextval from dual';
execute immediate 'alter sequence myseq increment by 1';

commit;
```

No error was raised, but nothing happened. When I wrote the SQL statements with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and ran them outside they worked.

Comment: @[APC] Yes, I don't get any error message (errors are logged). Sorry I was not clear before - I'm actually altering the sequence from the same DB that owns it. The PL/SQL procedure completes successfully. I'm using 10g 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi

Comment: Hmm I just tried it without dynamic SQL - it won't me put any alter statements inside the PL/SQL block, unless it's dynamic SQL. It says "Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following...". My intention is to have a procedure I can run to refresh data when I need it. And I will need to have a PL/SQL block to get the value from the remote DB - it won't work with a subquery to get the value for "alter sequence myseq increment by X":

Comment: @[APC] Hmm I just tried it without dynamic SQL - it won't me put any alter statements inside the PL/SQL block, unless it's dynamic SQL. It says "Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following...". My intention is to have a procedure I can run to refresh data when I need it. And I will need to have a PL/SQL block to get the value from the remote DB - it won't work with a subquery to get the value for "alter sequence myseq increment by X".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some code which dynamically sets a sequence to a new (higher) value. I have written this so it will work for any sequence in your schema.

```
create or replace procedure resync_seq
    (p_seq_name in user_sequences.sequence_name%type)
is
    local_val pls_integer;
    remote_val pls_integer;
    diff pls_integer;
begin
    execute immediate 'select '|| p_seq_name ||'.nextval from dual'
           into local_val;
    select last_number into remote_val
    from user_sequences@remote_db
    where sequence_name = p_seq_name ;
    diff := remote_val - local_val;

    if diff > 0
    then
        execute immediate 'alter sequence  '|| p_seq_name ||' increment by ' ||to_char(diff);
        execute immediate 'select '|| p_seq_name ||'.nextval from dual'
           into local_val;
        execute immediate 'alter sequence  '|| p_seq_name ||' increment by 1';
    end if;

end;
```

The procedure doesn't need a COMMIT because DDL statements issue an implicit commit (two in fact).

You can execute it and see the synced value  like this (in SQL*PLus):

```
exec resync_seq('MYSEQ')
select myseq.currval
from dual
```

Incidentally, the only way to reset a sequence (to its original starting value or a different lower value) is dropping and re-creating the sequence.

---

In 18c Oracle added a RESTART capability to ALTER SEQUENCE. The straightforward option ...

```
alter sequence myseq restart;
```

...resets the sequence to the value specified by the START WITH clause in the original CREATE SEQUENCE statement. The other option allows us to specify a **new** starting point:

```
alter sequence myseq restart start with 23000;
```

Excitingly this new starting point can be ahead or behind the current value (within the usual bounds of a sequence).

The one snag is that this new capability is undocumented (only for Oracle's internal usage) and so we're not supposed use it. [Still true in 20c.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/ALTER-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-A6468B63-E7C9-4EF0-B048-82FE2449B26D) The only approved mechanism for changing a sequence's value is what I outlined above.

Comment: +1 for a great answer. Sorry I was not clear before:( I'm actually trying to alter a sequence in the same DB.

Comment: @[APC]Thanks, man! It finally worked! I wish I could give you +10!

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't quite able to understand what you mean, but here is a wild guess:

I don't see it in your code, but you're talking about executing DDL (`CREATE`, `ALTER` etc.) on another database, so I assume you are using Database Links. *It is not possible* to use Database Links to execute DDL on another database. You might want to consider that.

---

After the information you provided, this might be what you need. And if you want to set the current value of the sequence, *you can't*, according to this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_2012.htm), you need to drop/create:

```
declare
  ln_lastNumber DBA_SEQUENCES.LAST_NUMBER%type;
  lv_sequenceName DBA_SEQUENCES.SEQUENCE_NAME%type := 'MYSEQ';
begin
  select LAST_NUMBER
  into ln_lastNumber
  from DBA_SEQUENCES--or @remote_db;
  where
    --Your predicates;

  execute immediate 'drop sequence ' || lv_sequenceName;
  execute immediate 'create sequence ' || lv_sequenceName || ' starts with ' || ln_lastNumber;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No sequence found!'); -- Or log somehow.
    raise;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear before:( I'm actually trying to alter a sequence in the same DB.

Answer (score 0):

Also, DDL in dynamic SQL pacakges requires

AUTHID CURRENT_USER

when declaring the package specification, if you want it to have the credentials of the current user

Answer (score 0):

I took the code provided by APC and modified as below:

```
create or replace procedure resync_seq
    (p_seq_name in user_sequences.sequence_name%type, 
     p_table_name in user_tables.table_name%type, 
     p_pk in user_cons_columns.column_name%type)
is
     local_val pls_integer;
     remote_val pls_integer;
     diff pls_integer;
begin
      execute immediate 'select '|| p_seq_name ||'.nextval from dual'
       into local_val;

       execute immediate 'select max('||p_pk||') from '||p_table_name ||' ' 
       into remote_val ;

       diff := remote_val - local_val;

       if diff > 0
          then
          execute immediate 'alter sequence  '|| p_seq_name ||' increment by ' ||to_char(diff);
          execute immediate 'select '|| p_seq_name ||'.nextval from dual'
       into local_val;
          execute immediate 'alter sequence  '|| p_seq_name ||' increment by 1';
       end if;

 end;
```